# What kind of Garbage Collection does Go use?

Tags: garbage-collection, go

Go is a garbage collected language:

http://golang.org/doc/go_faq.html#garbage_collection

Here it says that it's a mark-and-sweep garbage collector, but it doesn't delve into details, and a replacement is in the works... yet, this paragraph seems not to have been updated much since Go was released.

It's still mark-and-sweep? Is it conservative or precise? Is it generational?

Comment: For a long discussion of the history of the Go garbage collector up through July 2018, see https://blog.golang.org/ismmkeynote

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Plans for Go 1.4+ garbage collector:

- hybrid stop-the-world/concurrent collector
- stop-the-world part limited by a 10ms deadline
- CPU cores dedicated to running the concurrent collector
- tri-color mark-and-sweep algorithm
- non-generational
- non-compacting
- fully precise
- incurs a small cost if the program is moving pointers around
- lower latency, but most likely also lower throughput, than Go 1.3 GC

Go 1.3 garbage collector updates on top of Go 1.1:

- concurrent sweep (results in smaller pause times)
- fully precise

Go 1.1 garbage collector:

- mark-and-sweep (parallel implementation)
- non-generational
- non-compacting
- mostly precise (except stack frames)
- stop-the-world
- bitmap-based representation
- zero-cost when the program is not allocating memory (that is: shuffling pointers around is as fast as in C, although in practice this runs somewhat slower than C because the Go compiler is not as advanced as C compilers such as GCC)
- supports finalizers on objects
- there is no support for weak references

Go 1.0 garbage collector:

- same as Go 1.1, but instead of being mostly precise the garbage collector is conservative. The conservative GC is able to ignore objects such as []byte.

Replacing the GC with a different one is controversial, for example:

- except for very large heaps, it is unclear whether a generational GC would be faster overall
- package "unsafe" makes it hard to implement fully precise GC and compacting GC

Comment: Also the current garbage collector has a certain degree of parallelism  so it can run faster on multi-core systems.

Comment: @uriel: Yes, I mentioned this in the 1st item in my answer - the text "(parallel implementation)".

Comment: Is this answer still current?

Comment: c# garbage collector is precise and in c# like in go you can have reference to member of a struck and c# have an unsafe mode but i am not sure how it compare to go unsafe implementation

Comment: Go GC as of 1.3 is 100% precise now according to http://talks.golang.org/2014/go1.3.slide#4

Comment: Maybe time for a 1.5 refresh? I put a little raw material in this answer (the useful part may be links to the early reports of results): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684862/how-fast-is-the-go-1-5-gc-with-terabytes-of-ram/31686469#31686469

Comment: What about update this answer with 1.5.x just to make a good history log.

Comment: @Ismael I am sorry, I don't have time to deal with this this year (2016).

Answer (score 34):

(For [Go 1.8 - Q1 2017, see below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40317433/6309))

The next Go 1.5 *concurrent* Garbage Collector involve being able to "pace" said gc.
Here is a proposal presented [in this paper](http://golang.org/s/go15gcpacing) which might make it for Go 1.5, but also helps understand the gc in Go.

You can see the state *before* 1.5 (Stop The World: STW)

> Prior to Go 1.5, Go has used a **parallel stop-the-world** (STW) collector.
>   While STW collection has many downsides, it does at least have predictable and controllable heap growth behavior.

[image: https://40.media.tumblr.com/49e6556b94d75de1050c62539680fcf9/tumblr_inline_nr6qq8D9FE1sdck2n_540.jpg]

<sup>(Photo from [GopherCon 2015](http://www.gophercon.com/talks/garbage-collection/) presentation "[**Go GC: Solving the Latency Problem in Go 1.5**](https://sourcegraph.com/blog/live/gophercon2015/123574706480)")</sup>

The sole tuning knob for the STW collector was “GOGC”, the relative heap growth between collections. The default setting, 100%, triggered garbage collection every time the heap size doubled over the live heap size as of the previous collection:

[image: https://docs.google.com/drawings/image?id=sLJ_JvGfPfPnojLlEGLCWkw&rev=1&h=113&w=424&ac=1]

<sup>GC timing in the STW collector.</sup>

> Go 1.5 introduces a **concurrent collector**.
>   This has many advantages over STW collection, but it m**akes heap growth harder to control because the application can allocate memory while the garbage collector is running**.

[image: https://40.media.tumblr.com/783c6e557b427a5c023520578740eb94/tumblr_inline_nr6qqpmaJx1sdck2n_540.jpg]

<sup>(Photo from [GopherCon 2015](http://www.gophercon.com/talks/garbage-collection/) presentation "[**Go GC: Solving the Latency Problem in Go 1.5**](https://sourcegraph.com/blog/live/gophercon2015/123574706480)")</sup>

> To achieve the same heap growth limit the runtime must start garbage collection earlier, but how much earlier depends on many variables, many of which cannot be predicted.
>
> - Start the collector too early, and the application will perform too many garbage collections, wasting CPU resources.
> - Start the collector too late, and the application will exceed the desired maximum heap growth.
>
> Achieving the right balance without sacrificing concurrency requires carefully pacing the garbage collector.
>
> GC pacing aims to optimize along two dimensions: heap growth, and CPU utilized by the garbage collector.

[image: https://docs.google.com/drawings/image?id=sEZYCf7Mc0E0EGmy4gho3_w&rev=1&h=235&w=457&ac=1]

> The design of GC pacing consists of four components:
>
> 1. an estimator for the amount of scanning work a GC cycle will require,
> 2. a mechanism for mutators to perform the estimated amount of scanning work by the time heap allocation reaches the heap goal,
> 3. a scheduler for background scanning when mutator assists underutilize the CPU budget, and
> 4. a proportional controller for the GC trigger.
>
> The design balances **two different views of time: CPU time and heap time**.
>
> - **CPU time** is like standard wall clock time, but passes `GOMAXPROCS` times faster.
>     That is, if `GOMAXPROCS` is 8, then eight CPU seconds pass every wall second and GC gets two seconds of CPU time every wall second.
>     The CPU scheduler manages CPU time.
> - The passage of **heap time** is measured in bytes and moves forward as mutators allocate.
>
> The relationship between heap time and wall time depends on the allocation rate and can change constantly.
>   Mutator assists manage the passage of heap time, ensuring the estimated scan work has been completed by the time the heap reaches the goal size.
>   Finally, the trigger controller creates a feedback loop that ties these two views of time together, optimizing for both heap time and CPU time goals.

Answer (score 21):

This is the implementation of the GC:

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/mgc.go

From the docs in the source:

> The GC runs concurrently with mutator threads, is type accurate (aka precise), allows multiple GC thread to run in parallel. It is a concurrent mark and sweep that uses a write barrier. It is non-generational and non-compacting. Allocation is done using size segregated per P allocation areas to minimize fragmentation while eliminating locks in the common case.

Answer (score 10):

Go 1.8 GC might evolve again, with the [proposal "Eliminate STW stack re-scanning"](https://github.com/golang/proposal/blob/master/design/17503-eliminate-rescan.md)

> As of Go 1.7, the one remaining source of unbounded and potentially non-trivial **stop-the-world (STW)** time is stack re-scanning.
>
> We propose to eliminate the need for stack re-scanning by switching to a hybrid write barrier that combines a [Yuasa-style deletion write barrier [Yuasa '90]](http://www.yuasa.kuis.kyoto-u.ac.jp/%7Eyuasa/YuasasSnapshot.pdf) and a [Dijkstra-style insertion write barrier [Dijkstra '78]](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD05xx/EWD520.html).
>
> Preliminary experiments show that this can **reduce worst-case STW time to under 50µs**, and this approach may make it practical to eliminate STW mark termination altogether.

The [announcement is here](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/golang-dev/Ab1sFeoZg_8) and you can see the relevant source commit is [d70b0fe](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/d70b0fe6c4d1b1369b742ea5b7d4e6f0c50ffdcb) and earlier.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure, but I think the current (tip) GC is already a parallel one or at least it's a WIP. Thus the stop-the-world property doesn't apply any more or will not in the near future. Perhaps someone other can clarify this in more detail.

Comment: It is stop-the-world. GC potentially runs in parallel after the world has been stopped. You probably meant concurrent GC.