# what would cause code blocking in go?

Tags: concurrency, go

Since go is a **concurrency** program language and use `channel`(I use it almost all my code) or something else to synchronous `goroutine`.

And I also knew that go use a **scheduler** to schedule `goroutine` which means you should call `scheduler`(channel action, runtime.goSche or something else) in each goroutine and guarantee it would be executed.

Above is all my current limited on `go` and I use them to design my code.

But I also find it would occurred code blocking in my code. And it is hard to find where cause the block(even use **GDB**).

Was I miss something?

What else could possible cause the block?

And what things I should make attention?

**[EDIT]**: OK, since the code of my project is little big. I decide not show **standard** `go` code, just the general idea of the part that may possibly cause the code-blocking. Here are some code pieces of **file transmit** module in my project:

```
func(c *client)listenRead() {
    for {
        _ := websocket.JSON.Receive(c.ws, &package)
        switch package.Op {
        case fileUpld:
            c.fileMan.store <- package.Body
        case fileDownld:
            c.fileMan.downld <- package.Body
        case c.xxx:
            ...
        default:
            // bad package.
        }
    }
}
```

A **client** listening and receive message through websocket from another **client** and then forward the package according to `package`'s `Op` field to different **handler**, e.g.,`fileManager` shows below.

```
func(fm *fileManager) fileRouter() {
    for {
        select {
            case fs := <-fm.fileUpld:
                if window < filesize {
                    f.Write(fs.content) // client A write to file
                    window += fs.contSize
                } else {
                    f.close()           // close file
                }
            case fd := fm.downld:
                go fm.downldFile(fd)
        }
    }
}
```

A `fileManger` can receive file pieces and store to server when the **chan** `fileUpld` get data that send from `client`. And it can download file when it receive the `request` from a client, and it will generate a `goroutine` to do the job, which shows below:

```
func(fm *fileManager) downldFile(fd) {
    f := getFile(fd)                     // get the file that client A write
    b := make([]byte, SeqLength)
    for {
        if convergence < window {
            f.Read(b)

            // wrap 'b' to package 'p', for send

            fm.server.send <- p   // send to client B
        } else if window < fileSize {
            runtime.Goshed()
        } else {
            // download done.
            fm.done <- xx
            return
        }
    }
}
```

The major idea of my *file transmit module* is **client A** want to send a file to **client B**, and don't want to wait for the `acceptance` from **client B**, which means it will store to server first and **client B** will get the file later by download from server. But it could be possible that **client B** download the file while **client A** uploading a file. So there needs a synchronous between upload and download.

I use **three** variable to implement this: **window**, **convergence**, **filesize**. When **client A** uploading(write) file, **window** will increase it's value that the bytes it writes. And when **client B** download(read) the file, **convergence** will increase the bytes that it reads. `Write` happens only `window < filesize` while `read` happens only `convergence < window`. Just like:

```
+-----------+---------------+--------------+
|############||||||||||||||||              |
+-----------+---------------+--------------+
            ^               ^              ^
            |               |              |
       convergence        window        filesize
```

I knew this would cause data-race, but it also guarantee that `read` won't read the content that `write` has not write yet.(**BTW**:I don't have a solution using `channel` to implement it.)

The code-blocking occurs when I try to upload and download the same time(I slow the **client A** to achieve it). But it have no problem when I set `GOMAXPROCS` to 2.

Comment: If you have a code sample that demonstrates the issue you're talking about, it will be much easier to understand what you're asking. If you can get the sample to run on play.golang.org, even better.

Comment: @MatrixForg : I've re-edit and add the code sample. Hope it more clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider a Garbage Collector that will pause your entire program, so called "stop the world". On large applications with big memory consumption GC could "stop the world" up to 10 seconds, but it's the worst case. Here is a nice answer about GC in Go: [What kind of Garbage Collection does Go use?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7824353/45622)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is something new to me. But actually sometimes it would more longer than 10 seconds, and my application is not a larger one which may not cause by big memory consumption. I would like to know something structural consideration of the code.